# Android ScrollView Take whole device Space (Vertical)

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

My Fragment (`FrameLayout`) (w: `match_parent`, h: `fill_parent`) has two containing Layouts:

1. `ScrollView` (w: `match_parent`, h: `fill_parent`)
2. `LinearLayout` (w: `match_parent`, h: `wrap_content`)

I'dont get, why the `LinearLayout` just overlays the `ScrollView`. I wanna let stop the `ScrollView` at the corners to the `LinearLayout`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.my.stackoverflow.example.problemFragment">
    <!-- This is my Scrollview with an dynamic nums of TxtViews (Added by onViewCreated in my Fragment) -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/MessagesId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- Following a LinearLayout wich containing an EditBox and a Button)
    Take a look at the bg color, maybe helpful for you?-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MessageEditText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Sketch:[image]

**My Solution:**
I've added `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"`to my ScrollView and set my LinearLayout height from `wrap_content` to `android:layout_height="50dp"`
I think this is not a clean solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Altought this might not solve your problem: fill_parent has been deprecated. Use match_parent instead. Also: post your activity xml file so we can help you

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If the text that appears at the bottom is a TextView than you can use:
LayoutBelow and place it under ScrollView and Layout above of your bottom layout.

```
 <SrollView
   some height
   some width/>

  <TextView
      layoutBelow = scrollView
       layoutAbove = LinearLayout
  />

 <LinearLayout
    layout with buttons
  />
```

Comment: I mean that the TextView is an child of the ScrollView. The number of TextViews is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
tools:context="com.wembleystudios.engagementkit.service.socialbetting.view.activities.SignUpActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layout"
    >

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. My content of the ScrollView dont displayed at the device anymore. The LinearLayout is still at the bottom (good) but as i sayed, i the scrollview is now "empty"

Comment: the thing is that your Root layout has to be a RelativeLayout in order to use my response. Then attach your linear layout to the bottom of the root and the scrollview to the top of the Linear.

Comment: Hmpf that is a problem, because I build my App with one Activity. Every single "Page" is an Fragment. So, the Root Layout always must be an RelativeLayout(?). Now I've just added your RelativeLayout as the first child of my FrameLayout and as a Parent for all other Items. here is my pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LSYg3Adr

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired layout by replacing your root `FrameLayout` with either

1. `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight`

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <ScrollView
           android:id="@+id/ScrollViewId"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">
       </ScrollView>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   This option is very straightforward and you could easily add more elements to top or bottom of your layout. The drawback is that layout has to be performed twice.
2. `RelativeLayout` and `layout_above`

   ```
   <RelativeLayout>

       <ScrollView
           android:id="@+id/ScrollViewId"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar">
       </ScrollView>

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">
       </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

   This option is the most flexible when it comes to adding more elements to your layout. Layout also has to be performed twice though.
3. `FrameLayout` and fixed bottom bar height defined in `dimens.xml`

   ```
   <FrameLayout>

       <ScrollView
           android:id="@+id/ScrollViewId"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_bar_height">
       </ScrollView>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">
       </LinearLayout>
   </FrameLayout>
   ```

   This option is similar to your solution, except the dimension should be defined. It's not that dirty solution as you think, it's just not very flexible with adding more elemets to your layout nor editing your bottom bar layout. But the performance is way better because the layout is only performed once.